Lagrange equations with nonholonomic constraints
I am considering a mechanical system with lagrangian of the form
$$L \left(q,\dot{q}\right)=\frac{\dot{q}^{T}M\left(q\right)\dot{q}}{2}+\alpha \frac{\dot q^T A(q) A^T(q) \dot q}{2}$$
where $q\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the tuple of generalized coordinates, $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}, A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. The mechanical system is with the nonholonomic constraint $$A^{T}\left(q\right)\dot{q}=0.$$
I can write the Lagrange's equations of the first kind to express the equations of motion. Do the equations of motion depend on parameter $\alpha$? I have considered several examples and found out that all the terms with $\alpha$ vanish. But can't prove this in general case. Counterexample?

Alternative formulation:
Do equations of motion of two mechanical systems differ?

Mechanical system with lagrangian $L(q,\dot q) = \frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^T M(q) \dot{q} $ and nonholonomic constraint $A^T(q) \dot q = 0$.
Mechanical system with lagrangian $L(q,\dot q) = \frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^T M(q) \dot{q} + \frac{1}{2} \dot q^T A(q) A^T(q) \dot q $ and nonholonomic constraint $A^T(q) \dot q = 0$.


I'm really not understanding why the general case would be difficult to prove, you have basically said "I have a lagrangian $$L = \frac12\dot q^T~M~\dot q + \alpha V^T V$$ under the constraint $V(q, \dot q) = 0,$ does $\alpha$ matter?" and it's like I don't see why zero times any alpha is gonna be anything other than zero?

@CRDrost the equation of motion I've obtained looks like this, and it's difficult to understand how to remove $\alpha$ from here $\left(M+\alpha AA^{T}\right)\ddot{q}+\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}M\right)\dot{q}+2\alpha A\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q}=\frac{\dot{q}^{T}}{2}\frac{\partial M\dot{q}}{\partial q}+\alpha\dot{q}A\frac{\partial A^{T}\dot{q}}{\partial q}+A\left[A^{T}\left(M+\alpha AA^{T}\right)^{-1}A\right]^{-1}\left[\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q}+\dots\right]$

@CRDrost the reason why the equations can differ is you change sequence of steps when applying the variational principle. First you find variation, then apply the constraints or vice versa.

I mean, I understand why your mathematical machinery might be complicating the problem, but the way I see it, imagine $\alpha V(q)$, just like there's some particles rolling up and down a "hilly countryside", okay, $\alpha$ clearly matters. Now I say "but I want to constrain to $V(q)=0$", okay, so now we are imposing a track at constant altitude that weaves around the countryside, particles have to stay on that track like trains... it seems obvious that $\alpha$ no longer matters, sure the slopes are steeper/less steep but we can't fall down them anymore so who cares?

Maybe it's just that I don't understand nonholonomic systems, it just seems like there's some little dinky argument that says "we can choose generalized coordinates independent of $\alpha$ such that they enforce our constraints and $A^T~\dot q = 0$ in those coordinates, Lagrangians work even after domain restrictions like that so the EOMs in those coordinates don't have $\alpha$, so after converting back to better coordinates $\alpha$ never appears, so $\alpha$ must necessarily vanish from the correct EOMs however we derive them."

Are either of you acquainted with the notion of phase space (e.g. from Hamiltonian mechanics?)

The proof: The Lagrange equation of the second kind is
$$M\ddot{q}+\alpha AA^{T}\ddot{q}+C\dot{q}+2\alpha A\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q}-\alpha\left(\frac{\partial A^{T}\dot{q}}{\partial q}\right)^{T}A^{T}\dot{q}=A\lambda$$
where $\lambda$ is the lagrange multiplier and the notations $$\nabla_{\dot{q}}X\equiv\frac{\partial X}{\partial q^{i}}\dot{q}^{i} \\ C\dot{q}\equiv\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}M\right)\dot{q}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial M\dot{q}}{\partial q}\right)^{T}\dot{q}$$
are used. Then, solving for the Lagrange multiplier using the equalities
$$\begin{align*}
 A^{T}\dot{q} &=0 \\
 A^{T}\ddot{q}+\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q} &= 0
\end{align*}$$
I am getting
$$\lambda=\left(A^{T}M^{-1}A\right)^{-1}\left[A^{T}M^{-1}\left(\alpha A\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q}+C\dot{q}\right)-\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q}\right].$$
The last step is to substitute $\lambda$ into the source equation, collect all the nonzero terms with $\alpha$:
$$\alpha A\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q} - \alpha A\left(A^{T}M^{-1}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}M^{-1}A\left(\nabla_{\dot{q}}A^{T}\right)\dot{q}.$$
The last expression is obviously zero.

Original answer:
When applying the method of Lagrange multipliers [which I originally believed was the intended approach here] you first need to make sure that the constraint function $g$ [As I initially interpreted it, $\dot q^T AA^T\dot q$] is non-singular on the constraint manifold ($A^T\dot q = 0$). If the gradient $\nabla g$ vanishes on the solution $q^*$ (as it does here, because the gradient happens to be proportional to the constraint function itself), $\alpha$ (the Lagrange multiplier) would need to be infinite to offset an infinitesimal perturbation away from the constraint manifold. This is why the canonical approach to solving constrained dynamics involves introducing an auxiliary variable (constraint force) for each constraint (I believe this approach was described in the first answer to this question, which has been deleted by its author, but may reappear.)
ADDENDUM: (it turns out the question is slightly different from how I interpreted it)
Explicitly, consider the effect of introducing a Lagrange multiplier term, or set of terms, $\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k(t) g_k(q,\dot q)$ to a Lagrangian $L$, together with an arbitrary function of the constraint functions $G(g(q,\dot q))$. With these terms,
\begin{align*}
\partial_q L' &= \partial_q L + \sum_k\nabla_{g_k} G \partial_q g_k + \sum_k \lambda_k \partial_q g_k\\
&=\partial_q L+\sum_{k}(\nabla_{g_k} G+\lambda_k)\partial_qg_k\\
\frac{d}{dt}\partial_{\dot q} L' &= \frac{d}{dt}\Big(\partial_{\dot q}L + \sum_\ell \nabla_{g_\ell} G \partial_{\dot q} g_\ell + \sum_\ell\lambda_\ell \partial_{\dot q}g_\ell\Big)\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\partial_{\dot q}L + \sum_{\ell}(\nabla_{g_\ell}G+\lambda_\ell)\partial_{\dot q}g_\ell\Big)\\
\partial_{\lambda_k} L'& = g_k,\quad \partial_{\dot\lambda_k} L' = 0
\end{align*}
Notice that in the first two equations, the terms proportional to $\partial_q g_\ell$ and $\partial_{\dot q} g_\ell$ are equivalent. Hence, given a solution $(q(t), \lambda_\ell(t))$ to the original dynamical equations (obtained from varying $L$) we can obtain a solution $(q(t), \lambda_\ell(t)')$ to the new dynamical equations (from varying $L'$) simply by setting $\lambda_\ell(t)' = \lambda_\ell(t) - \nabla_{g_\ell} G(q(t))$. (If you're acquainted with electrodynamics, you can think of this as analogous to the gauge symmetry $A_\mu\mapsto A_\mu + D_\mu\Lambda$.)  Note that if $\nabla_{g_\ell} G(q(t)) = 0$ (as when the linear part of $G$ vanishes), then $\lambda_\ell '(t) = \lambda_\ell(t)$, and the equations of motion can in principle be brought into exactly identical forms.
As for "why" this is the case (for non-holonomic systems as well as holonomic ones), it might help to consider the "Routhian" dynamics of the system in phase space (where the constraints might be easier to interpret.)

No, $\alpha$ is not Lagrange multiplier. It is mentioned that $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, so it's just a scalar parameter of the Lagrange function. Lagrange multiplier $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^m$ here.

Is this a homework question, out of curiosity?

Nonholonomic systems are pretty tricky, I am not sure any student is able to prove the proposition correctly. I am just covering gaps in my education.

@MaksimSurov let me know if the new (and hopefully improved) answer is closer to what you had in mind.

I suggest that if $A^T(q) \dot q = 0$, then the 2nd term is zero regardless of $\alpha$ so it reduces to the same Lagrangian for all alpha, and therefore the equations of motion do not depend on $\alpha$.

My guess is the same. How to prove? Are there exceptions?

Substitute $0$ for that term in the Lagrangian equation, and then the whole $\alpha$ term goes to zero.

So, I think what Maksim Surov is confused about is why in general what you describe is equivalent to solving the equations of motion with the $\alpha$ term included. It might seem obvious (especially when constraints involve just the coordinates $q$), but it requires more work to prove mathematically that the equations of motion are in fact the same in either case. It's sort of like gauge symmetry (from electrostatics): it might be intuitively obvious (to some) that a gauge transformation cannot impact dynamics, but it's still a nontrivial mathematical result that can be proved rigorously.
